# Echo URL of large version of Featured Image

Tags: php, images, post-thumbnails, urls, headers

I use this plugin to echo the URL of a post's featured image in the header:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: Post Thumbnail FB header */
function fb_header()
{
    // Not on a single page or post? Stop here.
    if ( ! is_singular() )
        return;

    $post_ID = get_queried_object_id();

    // We got no thumbnail? Stop here.
    if ( ! has_post_thumbnail( $post_ID ) )
        return;

    // Get the Attachment ID
    $att_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_ID );

    // Get the Attachment
    $att    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att_ID );

    printf(
         '<link rel="image_src" href="%s" />'
        ,array_shift( $att )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'fb_header' );
?>
```

As it stands currently, it echo's the featured image. I want it to echo the URL of the Large version of the featured image. **How can I do this?** Just to note that all my featured images have a large version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the second parameter of `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`: `$size`.

```
$att    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att_ID, 'large-thumb' );
```

or

```
$att    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att_ID, array ( 900, 300 ) );
```

The size is passed to `image_downsize()` and there to `image_get_intermediate_size()`. If `$size` is an array WordPress will search for the best match in existing images:

```
// from wp-includes/media.php::image_get_intermediate_size()
// get the best one for a specified set of dimensions
if ( is_array($size) && !empty($imagedata['sizes']) ) {
    foreach ( $imagedata['sizes'] as $_size => $data ) {
        // already cropped to width or height; so use this size
        if ( ( $data['width'] == $size[0] && $data['height'] <= $size[1] ) || ( $data['height'] == $size[1] && $data['width'] <= $size[0] ) ) {
            $file = $data['file'];
            list($width, $height) = image_constrain_size_for_editor( $data['width'], $data['height'], $size );
            return compact( 'file', 'width', 'height' );
        }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the 900, 300? Does it search for those dimensions?

Comment: @AmandaBynes See my update.

Comment: @torscho I tested your first code, adding large-thumb to the line and it did not work. It returned the full image and not the large thumb. Is there any way you can confirm that it works for you?

Comment: `large-thumb` was just an example. You have to [add the image size in your theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) first. See also [tag:add-image-size].